# c# pattern or design for a lot of calculations

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I searching for design how can I implement a lot of calculations so code look clean and can be unit testable. This is how i done it right now.

I have form with blocks General, MainEngine, AuxEngine, Boilers, WaterBoilers and so on.
Every block have a lot of properties. For now my calculations class look like this.

I use partial classes for separate calculation logic between blocks

```
/// <summary>
/// My result class wich fill CalculationResult 
/// </summary>
public partial class CalculateBlocks
{
    private readonly IClassificatoryService _classificatoryService;
    private readonly IReportService _reportService;

    public CalculationResult Result = new CalculationResult();

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor with DI
    /// </summary>
    public CalculateBlocks(IClassificatoryService classificatoryService,IReportService reportService)
    {
        _classificatoryService = classificatoryService;
        _reportService = reportService;
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        CalculateGeneral();
        CalculateMainEngine();
        //and a lot more blocks
    }
}

public partial class CalculateBlocks
{
    private void CalculateGeneral()
    {
        Result.General.TotalReports = 2 + 2;
    }
}

public partial class CalculateBlocks
{
    private void CalculateMainEngine()
    {
        Result.MainEngine.Power = 1000;
    }
}
```

And my entities look like this

```
public class CalculationResult
{
    public CalculationResult()
    {
        General = new General();
        MainEngine = new MainEngine();
    }

    public General General { get; set; }
    public MainEngine MainEngine { get; set; }
}

public class General
{
    public decimal? TotalReports { get; set; }
    //... more here
    //... more here
    //... more here
}

public class MainEngine
{
    public decimal? Power { get; set; }
    //... more here
    //... more here
    //... more here
}
```

Comment: Pure calculations are typically _very_ unit testable - provide inputs, run the calculation, verify the outputs.  What part specifically are you concerned about?

Comment: incase you havent seen this, im sure you have.. but incase you havent.. great resource: http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is what you're looking for. Each block would be a seperate class implementing an interface.

Something like:

```
interface IBlockCalculator
{
    CalculationResult Calculate();
}

class MainEngineBlockCalculator : IBlockCalculator
{
    public CalculationResult Calculate()
    {
        // Calculation goes here...
    }
}

class GeneralEngineBlockCalculator : IBlockCalculator
{
    public CalculationResult Calculate()
    {
        // Calculation goes here...
    }
}
```

You can then implement the interface for each block. You can even compose them so that you can have a top level block with sub blocks.

Unit testing is simplified too because you can unit test each individual block calculation seperately.

```
[Test]
public void TestMainEngineBlock...()
{
    // Arrange
    var sut = new MainEngineBlockCalculator();
    // Set up your test scenario here...

    // Act
    var actualResult = sut.Calculate();

    // Assert
    // Assertion on actualResult go here...
}
```

Comment: I agree that was the first pattern to pop in my head. "Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it."

Answer (score 0):

Another concept that you may want to consider is the [Facade design pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered-1). Is more known to provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. And in your case

> so code look clean and can be unit testable.

I think it can be used to define a higher-level implementation that makes the subsystem easier to use.

Hiding the implementation details is also a concept of [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)). So the other users/cilents are being provided with the things they need to know/use and the actual processing is left to the one responsible for it.

If you are going to deal with fine-grained instances and sharing them [Flyweight design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/flyweight-design-pattern) can be useful too.